# How to display a custom message in HttpStatusCodeResult in MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC 5 it was possible to provide a status description, e.g:

`return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, "Could not connect to database");`

This is using `System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult`.

In MVC 6 with `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult` the only parameter is `statusCode`.

Shaun Wildermuth mentions the problem in this [post](http://wildermuth.com/2015/9/27/A_Look_at_ASP_NET_5_Part_5_-_The_API) - see Error Handling.

How can I display a custom message in MVC 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution I found involves building an extra class, but handles the lack of StatusCodeDescription nicely.

```
internal class ResponseWriter : ActionResult
    {
        private byte[] _stringAsByteArray;
        private int _statusCode;
        public ResponseWriter(string stringToWrite, int statusCodeToWrite)
        {
            _stringAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToWrite);
            _statusCode = statusCodeToWrite;
        }
        public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = _statusCode;
            return context.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(_stringAsByteArray, 0, _stringAsByteArray.Length);
        }

    }

public IActionResult OKResponse()
{
 return new ResponseWriter("Response description!", 200);
}
public IActionResult BadResponse()
{
 return new ResponseWriter("There was an error!", 500);
}
```

Credit goes to this blog: http://programminghave.blogspot.com/2015/04/custom-action-results-in-aspnet-5-vnext.html

I modified the StringWriterResult class in the blog to include custom Http Statuses as int.

Note, you should probably use HttpStatusCode in place of int in the constructor to adhere to HTTP 1.1 standards. I just used int to show a simpler example.

Hope this helps!